# Creating data hierarchy in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

So I have been tasked with creating a SQL Server stored procedure to assemble the geography hierarchy for an employee.

The system has 3 types of geography:

1. National Geography (Root)
2. Regional Geography (Level 1)
3. Territory Geography (level 2)

In the database the geographies table looks similar to this:

```
GeographyID | GeographyType | GeographyName | ParentGeographyID |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1             National        Nation          NULL
2             Region          South           1
3             Territory       Florida         2
```

There is also and employee table. A single employee can be assigned to any of the geographies above.

For example if employee 105 was assigned to the "South" Region there is an entry in an XREF table like so:

```
EmployeeID | GeographyID
------------------------
105           2
```

What I need to do is given an employee ID, build their geography hierarchy. So the result for employee 105 would look something like this:

```
EmployeeID | TerritoryGeographyID | RegionGeographyID | NationalGeographyID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
105          NULL                    2                    1
```

I'm at a loss of how to set up such a data structure. I'm hoping someone may have some insight on this problem.

Comment: Are you happy with maximum depth of the hierarchy being fixed at three. t-sql recursive query would be a good thing to search.

Comment: I actually have researched a bit, and thought a Recursive CTE would be a potential answer but I just didn't connect the dots to implement a solution to my pronlem using that. The funny thing is they want to eventually add more geographies or remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the expected result should show all the level, and the level are few there are solution that don't use recursive `CTE`, for example

```
WITH G AS (
  SELECT g.GeographyID 
       , t.GeographyID TerritoryGeographyID
       , r.GeographyID RegionGeographyID
       , n.GeographyID NationalGeographyID
  FROM   Geography g
         LEFT JOIN Geography T ON (g.GeographyID = T.GeographyID)
                              AND (T.GeographyType = 'Territory')
         LEFT JOIN Geography R ON ((g.GeographyID = R.GeographyID) 
                                OR (R.GeographyID = T.ParentGeographyID))
                              AND (R.GeographyType = 'Region')
         LEFT JOIN Geography N ON ((g.GeographyID = N.GeographyID) 
                                OR (N.GeographyID = R.ParentGeographyID))
                              AND (N.GeographyType = 'National')
)
SELECT E.EmployeeID
     , TerritoryGeographyID
     , RegionGeographyID
     , NationalGeographyID
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN G ON E.GeographyID = G.GeographyID;
```

In the `CTE` the `Geography` is partitioned and reassembled from vertical to horizontal, the main query `JOIN` the '`PIVOT`ed' data to the employee data, the ID can be changed to the location name by changing `[trn].GeographyID` to `[trn].GeographyName`

The partitioning can be explicited defining a `CTE` for every level

```
With N AS (
  SELECT GeographyID, GeographyName
  FROM   Geography
  WHERE  GeographyType = 'National'
), R AS (
  SELECT GeographyID, GeographyName, ParentGeographyID
  FROM   Geography
  WHERE  GeographyType = 'Region'
), T AS (
  SELECT GeographyID, GeographyName, ParentGeographyID
  FROM   Geography
  WHERE  GeographyType = 'Territory'
), G AS (
  SELECT g.GeographyID 
       , t.GeographyID TerritoryGeographyID
       , r.GeographyID RegionGeographyID
       , n.GeographyID NationalGeographyID
  FROM   Geography g
         LEFT JOIN Geography T ON (g.GeographyID = T.GeographyID)
         LEFT JOIN Geography R ON (g.GeographyID = R.GeographyID)
                               OR (R.GeographyID = T.ParentGeographyID)
         LEFT JOIN Geography N ON (g.GeographyID = N.GeographyID) 
                               OR (N.GeographyID = R.ParentGeographyID)
)
SELECT E.EmployeeID
     , TerritoryGeographyID
     , RegionGeographyID
     , NationalGeographyID
FROM   Employee E
       INNER JOIN G ON E.GeographyID = G.GeographyID;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d3d42/13)</kbd>